# Count people of certain age from a csv file (imported as a list of "people class instances")

Tags: python, oop

I am a python newbie and have been struggling learn to code python. I have a csv file that contains data as such:

```
name,age,sex,height
isabella,23,female,172
james,38,male,180
...
```

There are about 700 rows in this file. As can be seen, the first row is the header. I have created a "people" class and read the csv file into the class, where every row becomes an instance of the class. I store the class instances in a list.

```
import csv
class people:
    def __init__(self, name, age, sex, height):
        self.name = name
        self.age = int(age)
        self.sex = sex
        self.height = int(height)
peoplelist = []
with open ("Test.txt", "r") as csvcontent:
    next(csvcontent)
    content = csv.reader(csvcontent)
    for name, age, sex, height in content:
        peoplelist.append(people(name, age, sex, height))
```

Now I would like to find out the occurence of people with age 24. I have tried using "count()", but it only works with list of character as such "[2,4,5,2].count(4)"

1. Is there an equivalent "count()" method for my problem (age of all class instances in a list)?

I could solve it by creating a dictionary for all ages and print the occurrences for age 24:

```
agedict = {}
for i in peoplelist:
    agedict.setdefault(i.age, 0)
    agedict[i.age] += 1
print(agedict[24])
```

2. Is there a better way to do it? Ideally if I could just use "count()".

Thank you in advance for any pointer:-)

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not use your newly created `peoplelist`, but this could possibly serve your purposes. You can create a pandas dataframe using the `csv` file, and easily count the number of people of age 24 as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('people.csv')
count_twenty_four = len(df[df.age == 24])
```

If `people.csv` is in your project folder, you can reference it like I did here. Otherwise, you would need to specify the full path to the file.